# Problem with loading data with OkHttp request from static method

Tags: java, android, request, okhttp

I have a problem with my Android app for video games. The problem occurs when I make a call from static method to OkHttp to browse the game reviews.
When the OkHttp request was in the activity it worked fine, but when I moved it to another class in order to have cleaner code in the activity, the app is working strange.
Firstly, when I click the button to get reviews i get null data, but when I click again I get the data from previous click. If I open second game I get reviews from the first, if I open third game I get reviews from the second etc.
I have the same problem for all the API requests in the app.

Gif url from the strange behaviour:
https://thumbs.gfycat.com/OilyHardtofindDutchsmoushond-size_restricted.gif

Snippet of the static method in the Request class:

```
public class ReviewsRequests {

    private static ArrayList<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static ArrayList<Review> getReviews(int gameId){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        String bodyString = "fields *; where game = " + gameId + ";";

        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(bodyString, JSON);

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api-v3.igdb.com/private/reviews")
                .addHeader("user-key", Helper.API_KEY)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String jsonString = response.body().string();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Review>>(){}.getType();
                    reviews = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
                }
            }
        });
        return reviews;
    }
}
```

And this is the activity when I show the reviews in the recycler view:

```
public class ReviewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reviews);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.reviews_recycler_view);
        TextView noReviewsTV = findViewById(R.id.no_reviews_tv);

        int gameId = getIntent().getIntExtra("game_id", 1);
        String gameName = getIntent().getStringExtra("game_name");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(gameName);
        }
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        ReviewsAdapter adapter = new ReviewsAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        reviews = ReviewsRequests.getReviews(gameId);
        if (reviews.size() != 0) {
            adapter.setReviews(reviews);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else noReviewsTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your post lacks enough information to investigate the problem.  In particular, it's hard to help with code issues without seeing the relevant parts of the code—in particular, it's missing, at the very least, the Adapter code.  Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a null value because you are storing the value of "reviews" while making the api call. At that time, the function will return null value for reviews as it might have not got the result from the api. Instead, you just have to call a method of Activity when you get results in the `onResponse()` method to set the value of "reviews".

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "to call a method of Activity"?
What is the best way to do that? Can I do it with an Interface?

Comment: You can achieve it using interface. Create an interface with resultReviews() as a member function and override the method of interface in your Activity. Then call this method of interface from your ReviewRequests class.

Comment: Thank you, now it is working with non-static method.